# Best CSS tool to use

Tags: css, google-chrome, browser, firefox-addon

What is the best free css tool I can use, preferably an extension to firefox, chrome or IE? I would like to hover my mouse or click on parts of the webpage and it tell me where exactly the color is being set, where the margins are actually set in the css file, etc.... Thanks!

Comment: developer tools does this. inspect element

Comment: Tools for developers that do exactly this come build into most modern browsers these days.

Comment: You could try [firebug](https://getfirebug.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both Firefox & Chrome ship with Development tools like you're requesting.

Press <kbd>CMD / CTL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> in either browser or right click to Inspect Element

The left panel in both is the DOM structure, the right panel is CSS.

Hovering elements in the level panel will show padding (green) and margin (red)

You can also change CSS values in the right panel and see the results live.

## Chrome Dev Tools -

[image: Chrome Dev Tools]

Read about [Chrome Dev Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools)

---

## Firefox Dev Tools

[image: Firefox]

Read about [Firefox Dev Tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools)

Comment: In Firefox open the insepctor with <key>Ctrl</key> + <key>Shift</key> + <key>C</key> you can then click anywhere with the mouse and it will show you the color etc

Comment: @Noitidart, good points to add, updated my answer to elaborate.